# How can I conditonally format header cells based on top 5 subtotal values?

Tags: excel

If I wanted to conditionally format my header cells `CA3:DO3` based on range `CA5645:DO5645`'s top 5 subtotal values, how would I do that?

As in, based on all of the subtotals within those columns, only conditionally format the top 5 subtotals (color the header) of only those top 5 subtotals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select cell CA3
- Create a new Conditional Format rule using a formula
- Set this as the formula: `=CA$5645>=LARGE($CA$5645:$DO$5645,5)`
- Set the fill color
- Set the "Applies to" range: `=$CA$3:$DO$3`

Comment: this works GREAT! Thank you, I just have one more question.

If I wanted to apply this to a master sheet, and filter by manager, would it auto update since the subtotals would shift per manager? It's only referencing an aggregate view of the subtotals, but their top 5's will change with every filter I do by different manager

Comment: @nicklanta No, I don't believe it would auto update.  You'd need to add an extra condition for a manager name check.  Your best bet is to create a new question and include additional details.

Comment: @nicklanta, is the subtotal row always going to be the last number in the CA:DO columns? It's easy to reference the last row with a number.

Comment: @user10862412 after autofiltering, the subtotal should always be one offset from the last row of data that's being filtered